# How to defeat the final three predators in the alien campaign on Nightmare difficulty?

Tags: aliens-vs-predator-2010

Note: On Nightmare difficulty you have no checkpoints.

After fighting/slipping through the ruins you end up with a battle against a pair of predators before taking on a single predator.

I found several guides stating that you can defeat the predators by spamming the heavy attack button.  I had moderate success with this method but could not get the timing right to keep the final predator in an endless loop of knockdowns.

Are there any alternative strategies beyond hoping the heavy attack combo lasts long enough to allow you to perform the final harvest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternative strategy which seems to be unbreakable and fool proof.

The heavy attack combo mixed in with some ranged attacks should be sufficient for the first 2 predators but for the final predator I would recommend the following:

1. Attempt to grab the predator, which will fail as he knocks you back
2. Immediately hold block
3. The predator will always attempt an heavy attack, therefore immediately counter it with a light attack
4. Repeat step 1

Keep this pattern going until you can harvest the final predator.

You don't need amazing timing skills to pull this off.  The predator's heavy attack is easy to spot, and your weak attack is pretty much instant.  He will always perform a heavy attack if you are stood in his face performing a block.

The only difficulty is initially getting near the predator to perform the first grab (and this is hardly difficult because the predator doesn't need much help to get him to run for you).